# How to check if there is an element with enough elements after it with the same classname?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How would I have `popOver` show only when there is element with `counter` amount of elements after it with the same classname? (The counter will include the first element)

**Example :** (With counter = 3)

```
bar
bar
foo
bar
foo
foo
bar <-- PopOver would show up here
bar  
bar 
foo <-- PopOver would show up here
foo
foo
foo
```

**Example :** (With counter = 2)

```
bar <-- PopOver would show up here
bar 
foo
bar
foo <-- PopOver would show up here
foo 
bar <-- PopOver would show up here
bar  
bar
foo <-- PopOver would show up here
foo
```

```js
$(".bar").each(function(){
  $(this).append("<div class='popOver'>these would be recommended</div>");
});
```

```css
.bar {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;   
}

.popOver{
   width:400px;
   height: 30px;
   background: green;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 999;
   margin-left: 40px;
   opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
    <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
    <li href="#" class="foo">Foo</li>
    <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
    <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
    <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
    <li href="#" class="foo">Foo</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly improving on @Praveen Kumar's answer, this function should do what you want:

```js
function addPopOverEvery(n, selector) {
 $(selector).each(function() {
  var $original = $(this),
  $self = $(this),
  $is_pop = true,
  i = 0;
  if ($original.prev().is(selector)) {
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    $self = $self.prev();
    if (!$self.is(selector) || $self.find('.popOver').length) {
     $is_pop = false;
     break;
    }
   }
  }
  if ($is_pop) {
   $self = $original;
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    $self = $self.next();
    if (!$self.is(selector)) {
     $is_pop = false;
     break;
    }
   }
  }
  if ($is_pop) {
   $original.append("<div class='popOver'><-- these would be recommended</div>");
  }
  console.log($original.get(0));
 });
}

addPopOverEvery(3, '.bar');
```

```css
.bar {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;   
}

.popOver{
  width:300px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 999;
  margin-left: 40px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="foo">Foo</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="foo">Foo</li>
</ul>
```

With 2:

```js
function addPopOverEvery(n, selector) {
 $(selector).each(function() {
  var $original = $(this),
  $self = $(this),
  $is_pop = true,
  i = 0;
  if ($original.prev().is(selector)) {
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    $self = $self.prev();
    if (!$self.is(selector) || $self.find('.popOver').length) {
     $is_pop = false;
     break;
    }
   }
  }
  if ($is_pop) {
   $self = $original;
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    $self = $self.next();
    if (!$self.is(selector)) {
     $is_pop = false;
     break;
    }
   }
  }
  if ($is_pop) {
   $original.append("<div class='popOver'><-- these would be recommended</div>");
  }
  console.log($original.get(0));
 });
}

addPopOverEvery(2, '.bar');
```

```css
.bar {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;   
}

.bar {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;   
}

.popOver{
  width:300px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 999;
  margin-left: 40px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="foo">Foo</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="foo">Foo</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is a problem with addPopOverEvery(n); E.g. like @ZakariaAcharki said have you tried addPopOverEvery(2); because if there is 3 elements with same class in a row the first and second element get the popOver

Comment: Added catch alls, thanks for the feedback. How about now?

Comment: @Makaze Thank you for the answer, this is what I wanted.

Comment: @Makaze How could I do it if there was a class like `class="bar" class="bar" class="bar foo"`? I would only want it to allow the first 2 elements because they're the ones without `foo`?

Comment: @Makaze Sorry for all the comment, no worries about the previous comment with question... I found out I can do addPopOverEvery(2, '.bar:not(.foo)');  - Thanks again for answer

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `+` operator. The selector:

```
.bar + .bar + .bar
```

Selects the third consecutive `.bar` and does whatever you want to do.

```js
$(".bar + .bar + .bar").each(function(){
  $(this).append("<div class='popOver'>these would be recommended</div>");
});
```

```css
.bar {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;   
}

.popOver{
  width:400px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  margin-left: 40px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="foo">Foo</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="foo">Foo</li>
</ul>
```

You can use the `.repeat` function for making it customizable:

```js
var n = 3;

$(".bar" + " + .bar".repeat(n - 1)).each(function(){
  $(this).append("<div class='popOver'>these would be recommended</div>");
});
```

```css
.bar {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;   
}

.popOver{
  width:400px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  margin-left: 40px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="foo">Foo</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="foo">Foo</li>
</ul>
```

Where the `n` value will be number of the elements with same class.

Comment: Sorry I've just updated my question with bit more information.

Comment: @ChrisBeckett I have updated my answer. If it looks good, please accept it. Thanks in advance. `:D`

Comment: Have a look at my question, i've just updated it even more with a quick example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ChrisBeckett You said **consecutive**!!! And the second example is not consistent... Confusing mate.

Comment: @ChrisBeckett Saw it... `:/`

Comment: @PraveenKumar The issue is, he wants the popOver on the first element, not the third one. So you need to check if there are three without changing the current selection.

Answer (score 1):

That could not done using `+` sign since you don't have a specific `class`, so you have to do this programmatically using `if - else` condition and a counter to verify if the number of consecutive classes equals our counter, check the example bellow.

Hope this helps.

```js
var nbr = 3;
var count = 0;
var last_class = $('li:first').attr('class');

$('li').each(function(index)
{
  if( $(this).attr('class')===last_class )
  {
    count++;
    last_class = $(this).attr('class');
  }else{
    count=1;
    last_class = $(this).attr('class');
  }

  if(count===nbr){
    $('li:eq('+(index-(nbr-1))+')').append("<span class='popOver'> <= these would be recommended</span>");
    
    count=0;
  }
  
});
```

```css
.bar {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;   
}

.popOver{
  width:250px;
  height: 18px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  margin-left: 40px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="foo">Foo</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="bar">Bar</li>
  <li href="#" class="foo">Foo</li>
</ul>
```